# Bootstrap sidebar navbar save opened tab after refresh

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have in my bootstrap website a side menu using bootstrap css class:

```
<div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-nav">

<ul>
<li>
..
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

if the user clicked on a tab, and the page refresh, how can I save the opened tab by the user? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

1. if you're using angular ui router, you can use the stateparam, if not there are other two options
2. url params,
3. localstorage,

for the second point

```
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


 url with param page ?tab=home
$scope.tab = getParameterByName('tab'); // this is called in the controller if the page is reloaded
```

**###Edit###**
Then your add the param to your links

```
<li ng-class="active: tab === 'home' href="someurl/?tab=home"></li>
<li ng-class="active: tab === 'about' href="someurl/?tab=about"></li>
```

for the third option
you can add ng-click with function

```
$scope.setTab = function(tab){
    $window.localStorage.setItem("tab", tab);
}
```

you can get the tab by

```
$window.localStorage.getItem("tab");
```

You'll have to handle null if the tab value is empty

You can use `sessionStorage`
 this is temporal

```
 set value 
 sessionStorage.tab = "home"
  get value
  $scope.tab = sessionStorage.tab
```

Comment: I'm interested in the localstorage, can you help me please with that?

Comment: Ok sure, I'll get you an example

Comment: @ElioChamy If you're not clear about anything let me know ;)

Comment: hello, still have the problem, if I used the second option using params, I copy paste that function, and the menu will save the opened tab and should I call it when I click on specific tab ?

Comment: yeah, on click call the function